# Why email is not sending even if the path is working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mail-sender

This is a piece of code for genrating mail which works until I didnt attach path as a parameter . the thing is if I attach the path it didnt throw any error(no logs). Just the page started being unresponsive,and **debugger not even jump to next line**.
any help wil help me to understand my mistake . Thanks

```
public ActionResult Mailsending(string list)
      {
        try
        {
            string strIdeas = string.Empty;
            string Certpath =  System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UploadPath"];
            List<int> list = new List<int>();
            List<string> pramAttachment = new List<string>();              
            pramAttachment.Add(Server.MapPath(Certpath) + "MyPdf.pdf"); ///Path of the generated pdf.
            Submitidlist = new CommonBL().GetSubmiidListForGenerateMail();

            new CommonBL().UpdateIsGenerateStatus(ideaidlist, UserID);

            foreach (var item in ideaidlist)
            {
                strIdeas = strIdeas + item.ToString() + ",";
            }
            GenerateMyPDF(list); //Here pdf is generating
         
            string path = GenerateMail(strIdeas.TrimEnd(','));

            if (path != string.Empty)
            {
                new CommonBL().AddGenerateImagePath(path, UserId);
                new MailSender().SendMail((int)eMailType.GenerateMail, null, pramAttachment); // here path is added as parameter,and after this debugger not jump out of this scope.
                
            }               
            return Json("Mail generated Successfully."); ///no message showing
            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json("Error");
        }
    }
```

Edit :

```
public class MailSender : IDisposable
{
  public bool SendMail(short mailId, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> parameters, List<string> attachmentsPath = null);
}
```

Comment: Can you find in debugger what is the result of `Server.MapPath(Certpath) + "MyPdf.pdf"`? I believe you have to separate the two with a slash (\\)

Comment: Hi Martin, The debugger shows this result : C:\xyz\abcTest\Dev\PL\Documents\MyPdf.pdf with Count = 1 .

Comment: could you please confirm which line of code it is breaking (or becoming unresponsive)?

Comment: martin Here : new MailSender().SendMail((int)eMailType.GenerateMail, null, pramAttachment);

Comment: Is `SendMail` a method that you created? If so, can you include the code for that as well in the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding a point which apparently is also an answer of this question, is :
After debugging whole code, I found that my smtp server is not allowing to send me a mail, so even if the above code is right, it shows processing. 
So if anyone is working with above code will work fine.

An update : Now it works fine after configuring my mail service from control panel. So if any one wants to take reference from this can go ahead . the code is fine .

Answer (score 0):

Possibly still leaving lock on the generated PDF, so MailSender is not able to access it due to that exclusive lock. Can you send emails with files previously generated?

Comment: I dont think so,because i am already attaching images to it and that is working fine .